# How to Save Html data from a website to a text file using Xamarin forms and C#

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using C# and Xamarin forms to create a phone app that (when a button is pressed) will pull specific html data from a website in and save it into a text file (that the program can read from again later). I started with the tutorial in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvp7wvbyceo if you want to see what I started out with, and here's the code I have so far made using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwPx8QJn9Kk, in the  the "AboutViewModel.cs" file created in the video:

[Image link because this is a new account i guess and i cant embed images or something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxjlD.png)

Paste of the code itself (but the image gives you a better look at everything):

```
    private Task WebScraper()
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.flightview.com/airport/DAB-Daytona_Beach-FL/");
        foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='c1']"))
        {
            var itemstring = item;
            File.WriteAllText("AirportData.txt", itemstring);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public ICommand OpenWebCommand { get; }
    public ICommand WebScraperCommand { get; }
}
```

}

The only error i'm getting right now is "Cannot convert 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' to 'string'" Which i'm working on fixing but I don't think this is the best solution so anything you have is useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[HtmlNode](https://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v320/html/b90dc1a0-ebd2-d45c-64c0-86644db7bc62.htm) is an object, not a simple string.  You probably want to use the `OuterHtml` property, but consult the docs to see if that is the right fit for your use case

```
string output = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='c1']"))
{
    output += item.OuterHtml;
}

File.WriteAllText("AirportData.txt", output);
```

note that you need to specify a path to a writable folder, the root folder of the app is not writable.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: That takes away the error in the code, but then when clicking the button i'm given this:

System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'll keep looking into it though to see if I can fix that as well.

Comment: you need to determine us which specific line causes the exception (the stack trace should show you this) and then figure out which item is null